# R: How to use elements of one list to rename elements of another list with different length?

Tags: r, list

I have two lists `var` and `xnames`. I need to rename the elements of the first list by the elements of the second list. Unfortunately the second list is longer as the first one, so I only need some elements of the second list for that operation (in this case the first 4). 
I searched several websites for that issue but couldnt get a working solution for this (i thought) basic operation. Apologize if I oversaw something. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
var <- list(c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"))
xnames <- list(c("dim1", "dim2", "dim3", "dim4", "dim5", "dim6", "dim7", "dim8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` with *xnames* and `lengths(var)` to get the n first elements from *xnames*.

```
Map(function(x,n) x[1:n], xnames, lengths(var))
#[[1]]
#[1] "dim1" "dim2" "dim3" "dim4"
```